# Why does kotex put \dots in the midline rather than the baseline?

Tags: formatting, cjk, ellipsis

I have a document which needs to include a couple of Korean characters, which I'm doing via the "kotex" package, compiling the PDF with xelatex.

This package appears to be redefining \dots so that they sit in the midline rather than the baseline.

Here is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kotex} %compile using xelatex

\begin{document}

Why are my \dots midline rather than baseline?

\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:

[image: screenshot of mwe]

Why is this happening? What can I do to fix it?  Someone suggested using \ldots instead of \dots but that gives the same output; someone else suggested compiling using lualatex rather than xelatex, but that generates a ton of warnings *and* doesn't display the Korean characters properly.

Comment: Since `kotex` is meant to typeset Korean text and dots are raised in Korean… Loading `kotex` just to use “a couple of Korean characters“ is a sledgehammer. What characters do you need?

Comment: kotex switches to another font for the punctuation and that has the dots there. You can change that in lualatex with `\unregisterpunctuations{"2026}`, with xelatex probably some setting exist too, but the documentations of xetexko and luatexko are in korean ... But as egreg wrote, for a few words a system like kotex is overkill.

Comment: Adding `\XeTeXcharclass "2026 = 0` after `\usepackage{kotex}` should "fix" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to suppress this new format of `\dots`, you can add  `\XeTeXcharclass "2026 = 0` to the pramble, just after `\usepackage{kotex}`.

You can also use the korean dots in the following way

```
% !TeX TS-program=xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kotex} %compile using xelatex
\newcommand*\kdots{{\XeTeXcharclass "2026 = \XeTeXcharclassLD\dots}}
\XeTeXcharclass "2026 = 0
\begin{document}
    
    Why are my \kdots midline rather than baseline?
    
    Why are my \dots midline rather than baseline?
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks.